# Using cell value as range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a range (call it "A5:L10") be picked up from a cell. In other words, my code looks something similar to that below:

```
  Dim summ_rng1 As String
  summ_rng1 = Sheet11.Cells(17, 3).Value

  Workbooks(wb).Sheets(summ).Range(summ_rng1).......
```

Where summ_rng1 = "A5:L10"

I have done this same thing for the workbooks and sheets in my code and it works fine, but when I try to replace the range reference with the variable summ_rng1 it does not work.

Any idea on how to get the code to run with the range value as a variable, like that above? Thanks for the help!

Comment: this should work. are you sure for blaming the `summ_rng1` variable?

Comment: what is in your `C17` cell on Sheet11? it should be  `A5:L10` without quotes (not `"A5:L10"`)

Comment: I am working with multiple workbooks and accidentally had one open in a different instance of excel, which also happened to be the one I needed to reference on that line. Sorry for wasting your time, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. I think it is related to your `wb` object, which may contain the workbook itself, rather than the name of the workbook. Try this :

```
Sub testSub()
Dim myRange As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

myRange = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)

wb.Sheets(1).Range(myRange).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed it, see my comment above. Thanks for the help though!